# When to authenticate to server in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I have an iOS app that authenticates to a remote API. The server gives back a token that is used for all the next requests. The authentication call is a simple POST to /api/auth.

**My question is: where should I make this call in the app ?**

I don't know if I should use it in the AppDelegete (willEnterForeground or didBecomeActive), because it may slow down the app launch. Moreover, this is asynchronous and if I try to make other requests in some controllers while the token hasn't returned, there will be errors.

So I thought about doing it in the root controller, but in the case the app was in the background for a long time and comes to foreground in another controller it doesn't work...

The last option would be to watch errors on every call, and re-authenticate when the server responds with a 'token expired' error. In that case I should probably have a special class for HTTP requests and error handling ?

I don't know what option is the best...

Comment: I'd suggest a manager or wrapper for HTTP requests and also put in handling for different response codes. I do something where I send NSNotifications if tokens fail or have a version mis-match, etc.

Comment: Additionally, I suggest making calls to login from some type of login view. If you use a wrapper that will notify you of bad tokens you can skip re-authenticating when you're back to the app b/c you'll get notified when a bad request occurs.